# How do I forward requests from a client to a Windows Service running on Windows Server

Tags: spring-boot, iis

I have an Angular application deployed to/via IIS. This app is sending requests to REST endpoints exposed by a Spring Boot application which I am running as a Windows Service (The Spring Boot application is accessing a MongoDB but this should not be relevant, I think). The exposed REST interface is accessable via port 8080 on the servers localhost.
The Angular app is accessible as it should be but there seems to be a problem when the web app tries to access the Spring Application's REST interfaces. More specific: The client seems to be receiving HTML documents when he should be receiving JSON files.

I am new to working with IIS so beginner errors are not unlikely. I'm happy to share more information if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I read again the question, and understood something wrong:

Looks like you were sending requests to your Angular server. For development you should use the embedded web server (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html) in order to ease your server configuration steps. And from within the windows server, send request to localhost:springboot_port.

Once you want your service to be available for an external client, and to keep your service available/awake (something similar to systemd in Linux), you could try this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service